# isRemoved method for doubly linked list

Tags: java, methods, doubly-linked-list

I am currently working on an exercise and need help.
I have a Doubly Linked List(public class List) and need to create a Boolean method(isRemoved()) in the Nodes class (class Nodes) that checks if  an Element has been removed from the chain of Nodes, an Element y is in the chain of nodes if the following conditions apply:

Its predecessor is null OR its predecessor exists and y is its successor.
Its successor is null OR its successor exists and y is its predecessor.

I currently have getters and setters for the following three Objects. What would be the best way to create isRemoved()?

```
    Class Nodes{
     Nodes next;
     Nodes prev;
     Nodes Data;
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't method `isRemoved()` have a parameter which is the `Nodes` you want to check to see whether it was removed or not?

Comment: You code it exactly as written:  `inList = y.prev == null || y.prev.next == null || …`.  This rather depends on the specific structure of the list; though. I can think of one implementation of the list where inserting a single element and then removing it will result in the stated "in the list" condition remaining true.